# Button + image - any way to specify width/height of image?

Tags: android

I defined a button with an image:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="test"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/foo" />
```

Is there a way to specify the width and height, in dip, of the drawable being used? The rules for how the drawable scales aren't clear to me.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of drawable is `foo`? If it's a bitmap file, it has an intrinsic width and height that will be used.

Comment: Yeah it's a bitmap - isn't that problematic though - it will appear as relatively different sizes on different devices.

Comment: If you put it in "drawable" folder, it will be scaled to 1.5 times in 240 dpi deivces. So please put different size images in "drawable-mdpi" and "drawable-hdpi" folders and they will not be scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ImageButton` instead of `Button`. In ImageButton you can use `android:scaleType` tag with value as `"fitXY"` or other, as per your need to keep a check on scaling of image.

Answer (score 0):

Udayan is correct and also make sure you put image in button background, image may stretch,
better put in src. you can avoid scaling of image.